# ASP/VB.NET - Checkbox on CheckChanged not Updating with "changed" value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a checkbox that, when checked, I want to run an update procedure to update the value that the checkbox is passing. When I check the checkbox, I expect it to pass true into the stored procedure. But I'm getting the opposite. My handler is working correctly, and everything is passing into the procedure, but my checkbox value is the opposite of the action I just did (i.e. when checked, it sends in false, the value prior to be checked).

My debugging confirmed this. My initial research led me to think there was an issue with my ViewState, so I made sure to enable it in the HTML on my ASP side:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterStuff.master" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableViewState="true" CodeFile="Stuff.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test_Stuff" %>
```

But this does not seem to have changed anything at all. My checkbox is coded as follows:

```html
<asp:TableRow>
  <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkChecked" AutoPostBack="true" />
  </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

And on the VB side, my handler and call to the stored procedure:

```
Private Sub chkChecked_Checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles chkChecked.CheckedChanged
    UpdateStatus()
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateStatus()
    Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
        Try
            With sqlCmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandText = "UpdateStatus"
                .Connection = SqlCn
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.Add("@Checked", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkChecked.Checked
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            LoadPage()
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblError.AppendNewLine("The following error was thrown in UpdateStatus:<br>" + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is we might have 1 or 20 check boxes.

So, then which check box on the page does this refer to?

```
.Parameters.Add("@Checked", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkChecked.Checked
```

It could be "any" one on the page.

so, when you click the check box, we have to "get" or "grab" that current check box.

so, this should work:

```
Private Sub chkChecked_Checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles chkChecked.CheckedChanged
    Dim ckBox As CheckBox = sender

    UpdateStatus(ckBox.Checked)
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateStatus(bolChecked As Boolean)
    Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
        Try
            With sqlCmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandText = "UpdateStatus"
                .Connection = SqlCn
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.Add("@Checked", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = bolChecked
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            LoadPage()
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblError.AppendNewLine("The following error was thrown in UpdateStatus:<br>" + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

## Edit: Some follow up

this markup:

[image]

However, with above corrected:

```
<asp:TableRow runat="server">
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkChecked" AutoPostBack="true"
            
            />
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

And code behind:

```
check box check = True
check box check = False
```

so, debug window does show the correct output (toggle of values) for the checkbox passed to the routine.

However, since the check box button is NOT on the page, then how did you manage to wire up a click event?

Normally, when such a control is inside of a table (or grid view, or repeater etc.), then you can't (and don't) double click on the control.

So, what you do in in markup add/create the event this way:

[image]

And for a table, gridview or whatever?

Then you can freely wire up events. You note that the event in code behind is now wired up like it would be in c#. There is no "handles" tag for the class like this:

```
Protected Sub chkChecked_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

However, both should work.

I suspect there is more information and context required here.

however, I would try adding a runat="server" to the table. (and also a "id".

However, the click event of the check box should be "sender", and thus picking up the checked value should work.

Try dumping the Handles chkChecked.CheckedChanged.

(just comment out that stub). Try the intel-sense to create the code stub, and then cut + paste in the existing code into that checkedChanged event.

either way (checkedChanged event) should trigger, but since this is a table, and the checkbox (in theory) could be repeated many times, then I would use a actual checked changed event stub, and not a "handler" that could/might pickup any one of the check boxes clicked on.

Perhaps some update panel or some other details are missing here.

Comment: Debugged this and it doesn't appear to have worked. Upon checking the checkbox, my bolChecked value is still passing in "false".

Comment: Hum, that is strange. Note that you can NOT use chkChecked.Checked, since it is as noted inside of a table - so multiple instances could exist, and thus  you have to use sender as per example. This suggests that perhaps more then one check box control on the page is named chkChecked.

Comment: As noted, try removing the "handler" event as per above. I suspect there is a something in master page or some stray handler event here.

Comment: any control that has "asp:" as the start of its name, must have the runat="server" attribute.  Also, consider the datagridview or repeater controls to allow multiple instances of the checkbox control.

Comment: Correct about multiple instances of the check box. But, my code used "sender", so it only should ever pick up the one actual control used for click or onchange event.